# selenium webdriver is not recognizing web elements

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I am working with selenium webdriver and testNG. It seems selenium webdriver is not recognizing elements. what can be the reason for it. I have tried to recognize elements by xpath/css/id/link nothing is working. I am not able able to understand what is happening exactly. Can somebody please guide. I am also using the implicit wait command.

Comment: Obviously, the framework is not broken. Please, try to be more specific about your problems, show us a relevant piece of your code so we can reproduce the problem. What message/error do you see?

Comment: Which type of elements you are trying to recognize ? can you paste some code ?

Comment: Does it not recognize ANY elements? Please post a few lines of code in which you select an element.